# How to order by if else condition in room android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a list of items each item has ranking. Some rankings are zero. I want to query items by ranking ascending order if it is not zero and then remaining items which has ranking equal to zero. I hope it is understandable. :))

```
data class Item(
    val id:Int,
    val ranking:Int
)
```

Comment: Do you want two results or One ? one for all 0 ranking elements and other one for above 0 ?

Comment: I want one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boolean expression `ranking > 0` which evaluates to `1` for `true` and `0` for `false` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY ranking > 0 DESC, ranking;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0448ea3796c1b60a6b7dfaeb714774a9).

Comment: When `ranking > 0` evaluate to `0` and `1` ...this wouldn't properly sort.

Comment: @MartinZeitler did you check the demo I provide?

Comment: @forpas didn't consider providing multiple columns to sort, while the complexity of this is still acceptable for mobile (while pointlessly using `MAX()` wouldn't)... I was rather confused by your explanation, what it returns.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I believe that you misunderstood the question. It has nothing to do with MAX ranking. It is a simple sorting requirement.

Comment: @forpas I did will understand the question... while your approach has the issue, that once those records where added into an adapter, one would have to query again in order to sort them `ASC` or `DESC`. And that's exactly where providing `MAX() +1` as the value to return would help. The optimum would be to query once for the `MAX() +1` value, then pass it into the query for unranked items, as the ranking.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the query returns the rows sorted as per the requirement: *I want to query items by ranking ascending order if it is not zero and then remaining items which has ranking equal to zero*. Isn't this clear? No further sorting is needed.

Comment: From an SQL perspective this might be perfectly correct, not necessarily from an Android perspective ...I'd still favor your approach, because it properly would support pagination of records. But when using the common repository pattern, the sort-ability of the adapter isn't given, unless working around these `0` values - or reversing it altogether.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the question is about SQL: *I want to query....* and once again it has nothing to do with the MAX ranking which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be, to query twice and then merge the result sets.

```
@Query("SELECT ... WHERE ranking > 0 ORDER BY ranking DESC")
List<Item> getRankings();

@Query("SELECT ... WHERE ranking = 0")
List<Item> getUnranked();
```

One could also query once, but this needs pointless processing, because one needs to return `MAX(ranking) + 1` instead of `0`, so that the desired sorting would be possible. Without having benchmarked that, not utilizing the domain aggregate on each single row should be quicker. I'd rather add an [`@Index`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity#indices()) on field `ranking`, in order to speed up the query execution.

Comment: I have already done so. I wanted it to be done in one query if possible.

Comment: The question does not say so, therefore this is irrelevant. And I've also explained why this is a dumb approach, which only slows down the queries and drains the battery for no good reason.